# How to generate N-dimensional array of random values?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, random

Currently, I am writing this:

```
    x, y = np.array([random.randint(0, 9), random.randint(0, 9), random.randint(0, 9)]), \
           np.array([random.randint(0, 9), random.randint(0, 9), random.randint(0, 9)])
```

Is there a built-in NumPy function to allow me to do this a bit better?

> I said N-dimensional array not because I want to generate a random-sized vector with random values, but rather so others can apply it for their own vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(0, 9, shape)
```

For example, with `shape=(2, 3)`:

> array([[3, 2, 0],
>          [1, 0, 1]])